# Take first half of first string, and put it at beginning of second string based on user input

Tags: java, string

I am at the beginning chapters in my Java I class. This seems beyond what I have learned thus far.

I have to ask a user to input the first string. It could be anything. Then they have to input a second string. I have to take the first half of the first string and place it in front of the second string, then the other half of the first string and place it at the end of the first string. For example:

Enter something: ----
Enter something: word

Output: --word--

The only thing I've learned up until now is concatenation, indexes, and getting length. I have not learned arrays, if they can be relevant to this. What methods would I use to split this string up when I only know the strings after the user enters them? Even just informing me of unknown method calls would lead me in the right direction. I don't want (and can't) copy anyone's code.

Comment: Your description of your problem and your example does not match...

Comment: Have you learned [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring)?

Comment: Sorry @austinwernli, I meant to say the other half of the first string and place it at the end of the SECOND string. My bad. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example this is how you achieve that:

```
String firstString = "----"; //this should be read in from the user input.
String secondString = "word"; //this too should be read in from the user.
String finalString = firstString.substring(0,firstString.length()/2)+secondString+firstString.substring(firstString.length()/2,firstString.length());
```

Test code [here](http://ideone.com/XspSW5)

You should look into the Java [StringAPI for substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)). This will help you understand the code above.

Comment: I would add that in your example code there is a potential asymmetry in the output due to the truncation in division of the length of 'firstString' by 2.  For example, if 'firstString' is "1234567" and 'secondString' is "Hello" the result would be "123Hello4567". The reason for this is truncation in dividing firstString.length()/2.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I thought about odd length strings, but the assignment was to just split the string in half. It did not go any deeper than that. My assumption is that the instructor would take this into consideration, but I can ask to verify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring method of the String class
something like this should work:

```
int idxMiddle = (string1.length()-1)/2;
string1.substring(0,idxMiddle) + string2 + string1.substr(idxMiddle);
```